# Bigquery - Simba JDBC error with scala anorm

Tags: java, scala, jdbc, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query bigquery from scala (2.11.8) using Simba JDBC Driver (bigquery jdbc 4.2) through anorm (2.5.3) and play framework (2.5.8) on Ubuntu 16.04. This si my code:

```
class BigQueryController @Inject() (@NamedDatabase("bigquery") db: Database) extends Controller {

    case class VixStudioProduct(short_name: String)

    def test = Action {

        val names: Seq[String] = db.withConnection { implicit connection =>
            val query = SQL("SELECT name FROM dataset.table")
            query.as(SqlParser.scalar[String].*)
        }
        Logger.debug(s"products - $names")
        Ok
    }

}
```

but I'm getting the following error.

```
2017-03-02T12:58:44,428-0300 [error] [org.jdbcdslog.ConnectionLogger      ] - java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement: 
    throws exception: java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100038) Error getting query result object.
    java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100038) Error getting query result object.
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.getQueryResults(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQDoubleBuffer.getResultsResponse(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQDoubleBuffer.<init(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQResultSet.<init(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQSQLExecutor.<init(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQDataEngine.prepare(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.<init(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.jdbc.jdbc41.S41PreparedStatement.<init(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.jdbc.jdbc42.S42PreparedStatement.<init(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.jdbc.jdbc42.JDBC42ObjectFactory.createPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.jdbc.common.SConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.jdbc.common.SConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:310)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jdbcdslog.GenericLoggingHandler.invoke(GenericLoggingHandler.java:30)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at anorm.SimpleSql$$anonfun$2.apply(SimpleSql.scala:40)
        at anorm.SimpleSql$$anonfun$2.apply(SimpleSql.scala:39)
        at anorm.SimpleSql.unsafeStatement(SimpleSql.scala:61)
        at anorm.SimpleSql.unsafeStatement(SimpleSql.scala:53)
        at anorm.Sql$$anonfun$preparedStatement$1.apply(Anorm.scala:90)
        at anorm.Sql$$anonfun$preparedStatement$1.apply(Anorm.scala:90)
        at resource.DefaultManagedResource.open(AbstractManagedResource.scala:110)
        at resource.AbstractManagedResource.acquireFor(AbstractManagedResource.scala:87)
        at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$$anon$2.acquireFor(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:49)
        at resource.DeferredExtractableManagedResource.acquireFor(AbstractManagedResource.scala:27)
        at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$class.apply(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:26)
        at resource.DeferredExtractableManagedResource.apply(AbstractManagedResource.scala:24)
        at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$class.acquireAndGet(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:25)
        at resource.DeferredExtractableManagedResource.acquireAndGet(AbstractManagedResource.scala:24)
        at anorm.Sql$$anonfun$asTry$1.apply(Anorm.scala:228)
        at anorm.Sql$$anonfun$asTry$1.apply(Anorm.scala:228)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at anorm.Sql$.asTry(Anorm.scala:228)
        at anorm.WithResult$class.asTry(SqlResult.scala:181)
        at anorm.SimpleSql.asTry(SimpleSql.scala:6)
        at anorm.WithResult$class.as(SqlResult.scala:173)
        at anorm.SimpleSql.as(SimpleSql.scala:6)
        at controllers.BigQueryController$$anonfun$asdf$1$$anonfun$1.apply(BigQueryController.scala:26)
        at controllers.BigQueryController$$anonfun$asdf$1$$anonfun$1.apply(BigQueryController.scala:24)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:155)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:149)
        at controllers.BigQueryController$$anonfun$asdf$1.apply(BigQueryController.scala:24)
        at controllers.BigQueryController$$anonfun$asdf$1.apply(BigQueryController.scala:18)
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Action.scala:403)
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Action.scala:403)
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Action.scala:371)
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Action.scala:370)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:498)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:495)
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$2.apply(Action.scala:458)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:111)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:110)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:110)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:103)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:253)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:405)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    Caused by: com.simba.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100038) Error getting query result object.
        ... 77 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Required parameter jobId must be specified.
        at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:229)
        at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:140)
        at com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery$Jobs$GetQueryResults.<init(Bigquery.java:1248)
        at com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery$Jobs.getQueryResults(Bigquery.java:1221)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.getQueryResults(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQDoubleBuffer.getResultsResponse(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQDoubleBuffer.<init(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQResultSet.<init(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQSQLExecutor.<init(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQDataEngine.prepare(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.<init(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.jdbc.jdbc41.S41PreparedStatement.<init(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.jdbc.jdbc42.S42PreparedStatement.<init(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.jdbc.jdbc42.JDBC42ObjectFactory.createPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.jdbc.common.SConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.jdbc.common.SConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:310)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jdbcdslog.GenericLoggingHandler.invoke(GenericLoggingHandler.java:30)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at anorm.SimpleSql$$anonfun$2.apply(SimpleSql.scala:40)
        at anorm.SimpleSql$$anonfun$2.apply(SimpleSql.scala:39)
        at anorm.SimpleSql.unsafeStatement(SimpleSql.scala:61)
        at anorm.SimpleSql.unsafeStatement(SimpleSql.scala:53)
        at anorm.Sql$$anonfun$preparedStatement$1.apply(Anorm.scala:90)
        at anorm.Sql$$anonfun$preparedStatement$1.apply(Anorm.scala:90)
        at resource.DefaultManagedResource.open(AbstractManagedResource.scala:110)
        at resource.AbstractManagedResource.acquireFor(AbstractManagedResource.scala:87)
        at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$$anon$2.acquireFor(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:49)
        at resource.DeferredExtractableManagedResource.acquireFor(AbstractManagedResource.scala:27)
        at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$class.apply(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:26)
        at resource.DeferredExtractableManagedResource.apply(AbstractManagedResource.scala:24)
        at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$class.acquireAndGet(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:25)
        at resource.DeferredExtractableManagedResource.acquireAndGet(AbstractManagedResource.scala:24)
        at anorm.Sql$$anonfun$asTry$1.apply(Anorm.scala:228)
        at anorm.Sql$$anonfun$asTry$1.apply(Anorm.scala:228)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at anorm.Sql$.asTry(Anorm.scala:228)
        at anorm.WithResult$class.asTry(SqlResult.scala:181)
        at anorm.SimpleSql.asTry(SimpleSql.scala:6)
        at anorm.WithResult$class.as(SqlResult.scala:173)
        at anorm.SimpleSql.as(SimpleSql.scala:6)
        at controllers.BigQueryController$$anonfun$asdf$1$$anonfun$1.apply(BigQueryController.scala:26)
        at controllers.BigQueryController$$anonfun$asdf$1$$anonfun$1.apply(BigQueryController.scala:24)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:155)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:149)
        at controllers.BigQueryController$$anonfun$asdf$1.apply(BigQueryController.scala:24)
        at controllers.BigQueryController$$anonfun$asdf$1.apply(BigQueryController.scala:18)
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Action.scala:403)
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Action.scala:403)
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Action.scala:371)
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Action.scala:370)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:498)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:495)
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$2.apply(Action.scala:458)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:111)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:110)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:110)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:103)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:253)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:405)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

and this is the log of bigquery in google cloud platform

```
serviceData: {
   @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.bigquery.logging.v1.AuditData"    
   jobInsertRequest: {
    resource: {
     jobName: {
      projectId: "zentinel-datawarehouse"        
     }
     jobConfiguration: {
      query: {
       query: "SELECT id,short_name FROM vix_studio.product   "        
       destinationTable: {…}        
       createDisposition: "CREATE_IF_NEEDED"        
       writeDisposition: "WRITE_EMPTY"        
       defaultDataset: {…}        
      }
      dryRun: true        
     }
     jobStatus: {
      state: "PENDING"        
      error: {…}        
     }
     jobStatistics: {…}      
    }
   }
  }
```

I've found this reported issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906079
The cause is the same because anorm use prepared statement.

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Relevant part of the exception: _"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Required parameter jobId must be specified."_

Comment: why do I need that parameter? And how can I get it before run the job?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use this driver. My comment was just to highlight the cause. Maybe it will trigger you to solve it on your own, or someone else sees this and knows the solution.

Comment: this code works without. 
`connection = DriverManager.getConnection(bigqueryJDBC);
statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);
while (rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString("name");
    System.out.println("name: " + name);
}`
the problem occurs when I use anorm to execute the query

Comment: @GastónSchabas I am also facing the same issue. I have sent a request to Google Support. They are following up with Simba.

Comment: Hi @vaichidrewar, thanks for your answer. I've used conn.createStatement() as a workaround instead conn.prepareStatement() because that's the method that throw the exception